# Android: Get context of working activity at the time

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-context

Is there a method to return the working activity's context?

I started a process in the background, that need to make a toast in the middle of its execution, I need to have the current context so the toast can take it. The problem is I don't know exactly in what activity the user could be at the time the async task create the toast.

Any help please?

Comment: Post your code then...

Comment: **"I started a process in the background"** : What do you mean by that? What sort of 'process' and how is it started?

Comment: I mean I used AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to have the current context so the toast can take it.

Application context of your app is sufficient for Toast to show. You do not need Activity's context (and Activity is subclass of Context btw) for this.

Comment: Sorry I meant an alert not a toast! my bad.